# jQuery Mobile - cannot zoom-out page on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I use jQuery Mobile 1.4 and my web contains one page with a content that is wider than device width. See this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CMYK</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.min.css?r=$(REVISION)">
    <script src="../jquery/jquery.min.js?r=$(REVISION)"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.min.js?r=$(REVISION)"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>CMYK</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>This content is generated by the server:</p>
        <table style="width: 1920px">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: cyan;">cyan</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: magenta;">magenta</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: yellow;">yellow</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: black;">key</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: cyan;">cyan</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: magenta;">magenta</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: yellow;">yellow</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: black;">key</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: cyan;">cyan</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: magenta;">magenta</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: yellow;">yellow</td>
                <td style="width: 480px; background: black;">key</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On desktop browsers (Chrome, FF) i can zoom-in as well as zoom-out (to show all the content). ***BUT*** on mobile browsers (iOS, Android) i can only zoom-in, not zoom-out. How to enable zoom-out on mobile browsers? I know that I can set with=1920 in the viewport meta tag but it will affect all the pages with jQM.

Comment: you dont seem to have much text on your page so try without ---   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: @Tasos this is not solution for me because on the other pages I need to have width=device-width to be mobile responsive. Please note that jQueryMobile reads the head section only once.